# Problem when trying to deploy contract due to meteor's modules/scripts

Tags: web3js, meteor, requirejs

I have my meteor project
which when i run i get the following warnings:
First warning:

```
 Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () { return BigNumber; }
      intakeDefines @ aramk_requirejs.js?hash=a2cd915…:1278
      (anonymous) @ aramk_requirejs.js?hash=a2cd915…:1469
```

Second warning:

```
Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () { return utf8; }
```

and when i run my project i get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
at isBigNumber (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6e90e44e0c2b18ef12cb22415a388acb1e06ad7f:5598:19)
at toBigNumber (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6e90e44e0c2b18ef12cb22415a388acb1e06ad7f:5465:9)
at Object.fromDecimal (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6e90e44e0c2b18ef12cb22415a388acb1e06ad7f:5343:18)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6e90e44e0c2b18ef12cb22415a388acb1e06ad7f:2613:30
at Array.forEach (native)
at inputTransactionFormatter (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6e90e44e0c2b18ef12cb22415a388acb1e06ad7f:2612:8)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6e90e44e0c2b18ef12cb22415a388acb1e06ad7f:2910:28
at Array.map (native)
at Method.formatInput (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6e90e44e0c2b18ef12cb22415a388acb1e06ad7f:2909:32)
at Method.toPayload (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6e90e44e0c2b18ef12cb22415a388acb1e06ad7f:2935:23)
```

The line of code where the problem occurs is this: `web3.eth.contract(abi).new({data: code,gas:10000}, function (err, contract) {..irrelevant code..}` After searching on the internet I think that it is require.js's fault and how the scripts are called but still don't know how to fix it. I already looked over the documentation but still need some help.